# Can I cool 540 sq. ft. with a single A/C unit?

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a small apartment - about 540sq ft.

## The layout:

[image]
<sup>*Click for larger view*</sup>

The red square would be the internal unit, and to the left and right I have 2 rooms.

I also have a 6 month old little girl, so I wouldn't want a unit in her room. I'm thinking that I could have a single unit, that would reasonably cool both rooms indirectly.

Will it be pointless? Should I go for a multi-split?

## More info:

The doors stay open most of the time, and the windows are only on the right side of the building (as you see it in the picture). Each room also has a balcony, and that takes most of the sunlight. The sun enters the room usually after 4 pm during the summer.

The average temperature in the summer is around 90F, but can go up to 105F for stretches of 4-5 days.

Comment: there is a proportion to be observed for the air to be cooled down, between the square feet of the whole area (home or apartment) against the basic "1 ton" of equipment capacity. One ton = 12,000 BTU which is barely enough force in your a/c unit to transform the air of 400 sq.ft from hot to fresh. I hope this gives you the idea how to size the equipment properly according to the square footage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone would need a lot of detailed information about your apartment to determine the actual cooling load. Even assuming you have a properly sized air con unit, it seems silly to me to spend good money on an air con system and then need to rely on box fans to get it to work right. You basically should have a fan/coil unit in each room that you require to be kept at a comfortable temperature.

If you do not, one room will inevitably be too cold and the other too hot. But on the average I suppose you could claim your apartment is comfortable ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about a ductless mini-split AC system.

Some more information will be required to provide a good answer as to the total required cooling capacity. The answer will depend very much on the climate and aspects of the building like number/location of windows, sun/shade, etc.

Once you have an appropriately sized unit, then the issue will be moving the cool air around the apartment. If you are OK with leaving doors open, and perhaps using some portable fans or ceiling fans to aid air flow, then I think you could potentially make the whole place comfortable. If doors between rooms are closed, then the temperature will not equilibrate as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you are going to have some variance between rooms.  Maybe by as much as 5-10 degrees F.  I would suggest having a way to get the cold air out of the main room and into the others - basic box fans would work.  Also you have to understand that if you want the subrooms very comfortable then you may have to have unit running a lot and the main room a bit chilly.  Also subrooms will need to be closed of sunlight to reduce temp variance during the day.